# Generic OAuth Provider for Okta in Azure Bot channels registration

Tags: botframework

Is there any documentation to configure **Okta** as **generic OAuth Provider** in Azure bot channels registration

Answer (score 0):

We do not have any specific documentation for configuring Okta as a generic OAuth provider. But you can refer to **Oauth generic providers** [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-identity-providers?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=adv1%2Cga2#oauth-generic-providers) and the **Add Authentication to a bot** [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp) on the bot framework end. For the Okta authentication implementation, you can refer to the Authentication API [doc](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/authn/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup the app integration in Okta, the OAuth connection settings of Okta in your Azure bot service are as follows:

1. **Name**: is up to you.
2. **Service Provider:** is **Generic Oauth 2**.
3. **Client id**: from your Okta App integration
4. **Client secret**: from your Okta App integration
5. **Authoriation URL**: [Auth Server Issuer Url]/v1/authorize
6. **Token URL**: [Auth Server Issuer Url]/v1/token
7. **Refresh URL**:  [Auth Server Issuer Url]/v1/token *(Yes, it
   intentionally is /token and not /refresh.)*
8. **Scopes**: openid, profile, email, offline_access

Took me a while to get all the settings right so I blogged about it. Hope it helps :) https://blog.try-it.dev/azure-bot-authentication-using-okta-identity/

[image: Okta oAuth Settings for Azure Bot Service]