# Okta SSO integration with botframework

Tags: botframework, okta, facebook-timeline

I have been given a requirement to see if Okta can be used as an sso with the .net core bot framework.  I have searched online but I haven't seen any examples of Okta being used. Not knowing Okta well I wanted to see if there is any examples I could use as a reference.

Comment: I haven't seen any specific references for this kind of a requirement but this one looks something to start with. :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63013273/generic-oauth-provider-for-okta-in-azure-bot-channels-registration

Comment: Along with the above comment, you can also take a look at https://blog.try-it.dev/azure-bot-authentication-using-okta-identity/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-sso?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp%2Ceml